# MiniProfiler V4 não renderiza no MVC5 + EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, desempenho, asp.net-profile

Bom dia, pessoal.

Instalei o `MiniProfiler v4` no meu projeto `ASP.NET MVC5` para checar alguns pontos de lentidão, porém, a tela de resultados não é renderizada na minha view - e nem aparece erro no Console, simplesmente não acontece nada.

Enfim, estou ficando sem saídas. Segui a maioria dos tópicos similares daqui e do Stack internacional, mas não consegui resolver esse problema.

Talvez seja algo simples que não estou conseguindo enxergar. Podem me ajudar?

### Edit: Problema resolvido. Vou manter a pergunta completa e minhas atualizações até chegar na solução, pode ser útil para alguém, visto que o conteúdo sobre MiniProfiller é bem esparso.

---

## Passos da instalação:

- 1 Instalei o `MiniProfiler` via Nuget; Instalei o `MiniProfilerEF` via Nuget;
- 2 No `Global.asax`, adicionei algumas configurações do MiniProfiler:

No `Application_Start`;

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


        //Inicialização do MiniProfiler EF
        MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
    }
```

No `Application_BeginRequest`;

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        //Só faço o Profiling se for uma requisição local
        if (Request.IsLocal)
        {
            MiniProfiler.StartNew();
        }
    }
```

E, por fim, no `Application_EndRequest`:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        MiniProfiler.Current?.Stop();
    }
```

- 3 No `web.config` da raiz do projeto, fiz a configuração de handlers dentro da tag `< system.webServer>`:

  ```
  <handlers><add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" /></handlers>
  ```
- 4 No `_Layout.cshtml`, adicionei a referencia e a chamada do MiniProfiler:

A referencia `@using StackExchange.Profiling` no topo e, na linha anterior ao `< /body>`, a chamada do render:

`@MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes()`

- 5 Executei o projeto. 
  Após esses passos, o *pop up* com as estatísticas já deveria aparecer.

---

## Pacotes instalados do MiniProfiler:

> MiniProfiler version="4.0.138" targetFramework="net461"
>
> MiniProfiler.EF version="2.1.0" > targetFramework="net461"
>
> MiniProfiler.EF6 version="4.0.138" targetFramework="net461"
>
> MiniProfiler.Shared version="4.0.138 targetFramework="net461"

E do MVC:

> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net461"

---

## Informações adicionais

- Já tentei reinstalar o MiniProfiller;
- Já tentei seguir o tutorial descrito no [site oficial do MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNet)
- Já segui alguns tutoriais externos, mas poucos eram da v4 e nenhum resolveu o problema;
- Já tentei limpar a solução, recompilar, etc;
- Já fiz um `Update-Package`;
- Já baixei o projeto completo do gerenciador de versão e tentei novamente.
- No código fonte da pagina gerada no navegador, a chamada `@MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes()` não gera código nenhum.
- Se tento acessar o `http://localhost:porta/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js`, recebo um erro 404, então imagino que o problema venha dai;
- No Console do navegador, não tenho erro nenhum.

---

## Atualizações

- Em 02/10 às 14:23: Se eu usar o `@MiniProfiler.Current.RenderPlainText()` no `_Layout`, tenho um texto renderizado:

> DVLP_01 at 02/10/2018 17:21:13 MiniProfiler = ms (sql = 214,4ms in 4 cmds)

---

- Em 02/10 às 15:23: Debugando `@MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes()`, vejo que a chamada ao `public static IHtmlString RenderIncludes(...)` acontece, a variavel `profiler` vai preenchida, mas a `settings` vai nula, então, no trecho abaixo, é retornada a string vazia.

`if (profiler == null) return _empty;
    var settings = profiler.Options as MiniProfilerOptions;
    if (settings == null) return _empty;`

Estou pesquisando sobre isso agora. O problema deve estar ai.

---

- Em 02/10 às 16:00: Realmente, parte do problema era a variável `settings` nula.

Editei o `Global.asax` adicionando a configuração do `MiniProfilerOptions` no `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            MiniProfiler.Configure(new MiniProfilerOptions
            {
                // Rota base será ~/profiler, 
                //então teremos /profiler/mini-profiler-includes.js
                RouteBasePath = "~/profiler",

                // Defino para conexões locais
                ResultsAuthorize = request => request.IsLocal,

                //Rastrear abertura e fechamento de conexões
                TrackConnectionOpenClose = true
            }
            //Configurações adicionais
            .AddViewProfiling() //Adiciona um a view MVC view
            );

            //Inicialização do MiniProfilerEF6 (EntityFramework 6)
            MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
        }
```

E, a variável não vai mais nula e não retorna uma string vazia, mas sim o script.

```
<script async="async" id="mini-profiler" src="/profiler/includes.min.js?v=4.0.138+gcc91adf599" data-version="4.0.138+gcc91adf599" data-path="/profiler/" data-current-id="ad7560c4-69a1-4d6a-a060-cc7629f1d1af" data-ids="dfd38a97-76ce-4915-8a69-63892f510774,e289321b-b7f3-4b64-95a1-d1b102647069,ad7560c4-69a1-4d6a-a060-cc7629f1d1af" data-position="Left" data-authorized="true" data-max-traces="15" data-toggle-shortcut="Alt+P" data-trivial-milliseconds="2.0" data-ignored-duplicate-execute-types="Open,OpenAsync,Close,CloseAsync"></script>
```

Agora falta descobrir porquê não abriu. No Console, tenho um erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

- Em 02/10 às 15:50: **Problema resolvido**.

Identifiquei que o erro descrito acima era causado por ter o retorno *404* no `/profiler/includes.min.js?v=4.0.138+gcc91adf599`. Isso acontece pois, quando criei a configuração personalizada no `Application_Start`, defini o caminho `RouteBasePath = "~/profiler"`, mas o `path` no `web.config` permanecia com `mini-profiler-resources/*`.

Alterei o `handlers` descrito no passo 3 para:

```
    <handlers><add name="MiniProfiler" path="profiler/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" /></handlers>
```

e adicionei o `filters` com o `ProfilingActionFilter` no arquivo `FilterConfig`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter());
        }
```

E funcionou. O arquivo é encontrado e o popup aparece!

Comment: O mais interessante seria você manter a dúvida original e postar a resolução como resposta e aceita-la, isso auxilia no funcionamento do site, não se esqueça de fazer o [tour] para entender melhor como funciona o SOPt

Comment: Barbetta, obrigado! As minhas atualizações foram apenas complementares, não alterei nada na pergunta original. Você acha que devo manter desse jeito ou remover o campo "Atualizações" adicionando-o em uma resposta?

Comment: E mais uma coisa... enquanto você adicionava o comentário eu escrevia a resposta. rs Posso edita-la, se você achar que da outra forma fica melhor. Abraço!

Comment: KKK verdade, foi tudo junto. Eu acho válido remover o que solução da pergunta e  manter como resposta, só dela estar marcada como correta e ter todo conteúdo lá vai ajudar muita gente, inclusive eu que vou testar essa ferramenta :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução detalhada está descrita no campo **Atualizações** da própria pergunta, mas, vou adicionar um resumo:

1. Certificar-se que os pacotes foram instalados corretamente;
2. Certificar-se que o `Application_Start()` tem a configuração do profiler e a inicialização do profiler para o EF;
3. Certificar-se que o `web.config` tem o `handlers` configurado de acordo com o path personalizado no `Application_Start()`;
4. Certificar-se que o `ProfilingActionFilter` foi adicionado no `FilterConfig`;

Por fim, executar a solução forçando uma atualização (Control+F5) e analisar os resultados no Console e Sources. Se o arquivo `/profiler/includes.min.js` não estiver visível (*404* ou uma pagina de erro personalizada), analisar as regras de permissão/restrição de acesso - provavelmente, algo relacionado ao ponto 3 desta resposta.

Seguindo esses passos consegui solucionar o problema aqui. Leia atentamente a pergunta e faça analogias com seu cenário, provavelmente você também conseguirá.